# How is Latium pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, ecclesiastical-latin, consonants

The [Merriam Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latium) gives the following pronunciation: `\ˈlā-sh(ē-)əm\`.

But this doesn't sound right to me. I have never heard the consonant 't' pronounced this way in Latin. Which leads me to a few questions.

1. How did the Romans pronounce *Latium*?
2. How is *Latium* pronounced in the ecclesiastical and English pronunciation systems?
3. Is there a difference in pronunciation of this word between these three systems?

Comment: That pronunciation is for the English word "Latium," not the Latin word "Latium."  Hence the difference in the T.

Comment: English pronunciation of anything foreign is so messed up it's hardly believable anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forgive me if I use [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) notation. As a non-native speaker of English, I still have some difficulty with English vowels and don't really feel comfortable using English-based systems as Webster's

- In Classical *reconstructed* pronunciation, it would be **['la.ti.ũ:]**. Germans and classicists prefer this one. Note that this is how Romans *most likely* pronounced it, since there is only indirect (yet quite convincing) evidence. If you are not familiar with IPA, ũ means *oo* as in g*oo*se, but *nasalized*.
- In Ecclesiastical pronunciation, it is **['la.tsi.um]**: *ti*+vowel not preceded by s becomes *tsi*. This one was settled down in the 19th century and is well-documented. Although it is most likely not *the original way* to pronounce Classical Latin, it has ancient roots and enjoys some official status. It is mostly based in how Italian Latinists and churchmen pronounced Latin at the time, and is consistent with what it likely sounded in medieval times.

In both cases: 1) unlike English, *t* is **not** aspirated (think of the sound of *t* in romance languages, like Spanish, French, or Italian). 2) *i* and *u* do not form a diphthong, hence they are in separate syllables. 3) since the i is short, the stress goes in the third-to-last syllable  (i.e., the first one in this case) 4) *a* as in father, *i* as ee in bee, *u* as oo in boot, but all shorter.

Regarding English pronunciation, there is an [intricate set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) of rules to pronounce Latin in an academic context. It is basically the effect of the same sound changes that affected English plus some academic corrections along history. As a consequence, the very set of rules also changed with time. Following it, you apparently get (thanks Sumelic):

- (Trad. English pronunciation:) **['leɪ.ʃəm]**, admitting some variants, it seems, like **['leɪ.ʃɨəm]**, which is pretty close to (if not the same as) what MW says. As Nathaniel suggests, this is how most English-speaking Latin scholars pronounced Latin *before* the time when *Reconstructed* and *Ecclesiastical* pronunciations took force and pushed most local variants close to extinction.

The fact that MW offers a different pronunciation may obey the fact that English evolves with use (rather than what academics say), and the current pronunciation of original Latin words may have departed from what scholars say. For what it's worth, Dictionary.com offers the following one: [[**ley**-shee-*uh* m]](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/latium?s=t), which —correct me if I am wrong— is (almost) consistent with MW's.

Comment: Your blurb on the Ecclesiastical gives the impression that 'tsi' dates to the 1800s.  Actually the sequence is [t + i + vowel] and it dates back to Medieval Latin, as evidenced in the frequent interchange of -cia and -tia spellings in Early and High Medieval literature (c + i was "tsee" in Medieval Latin since perhaps around the 6th century), as well as in their being rhymed in contemporary poetry such as Thomas Aquinas' hymn "Adore Te Devote".

Comment: @Coemgenus better now? See also: [this question about the timing of palatalization](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/44/when-did-c-before-e-or-i-start-to-be-pronounced-as-ts-in-contrast-to-cl/117#117)

Comment: Yes, much better. Good link too.

Comment: I am surprised you say that Germans prefer the classical way as the traditional German regional pronunciation uses /tsi/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_regional_pronunciation

Comment: @VladimirF: I think that the traditional German pronunciation of Latin, like the traditional English pronunciation of Latin, has become unpopular among German scholars and students of Latin (despite having a continued influence on the pronunciation of Latin-derived terms in German).

Comment: @sumelic I wouldn't have expected that. Here in the Czech Republic the local pronunciation, almost identical to the German one, appears to be very common. At least among non-specialists (history, medicine, biology...). I even went to check some lecture notes for history courses and that is what is generally taught.

Comment: @Asteroides A good example of an exception to this, is the explicit instructions on the pronunciation of the Latin in _Carmina Burana_: The composer states that it shall be performed with German pronunciation, _not_ Italian – and it definitely works brilliantly with the feel of the piece.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently this pronunciation of Latium is similar to the one that the French use.

I had the same question when I visited Rome and realized that the modern name of Lazio is the Italian pronunciation of Latium. Since -tion in English corresponds to -zione in Italian, I concluded that the -ti- in La**ti**um should probably be pronounced like the -ti- in e.g. ini**ti**a**ti**on (just like how, in Italian, the -zi- in La**zi**o is pronounced like the -zi- in ini**zi**a**zi**one and, in Spanish, the -ci- in La**ci**o is pronounced like the -ci- in ini**ci**a**ci**ón).

Since English adopted many of the French sound changes to the Latin language (well, at least as best they could given the phonology of the English language), the fact that -ti- is pronounced like -sh- should not be surprising.

In linguistics, I believe this phenomenon is known as [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)). It's the same reason that diurnal became giorno in Italian.

Disclaimer: I am in no sense a linguist and do not speak any of the languages I mentioned above (except for English, of course). I'm just someone with an untrained ear who is sharing an observation I made while traveling abroad.

Comment: Random fun fact: palatalization is the reason we have soft c and soft g. In the case of soft c, the "k sound" became a "ch sound" which simplified to an "s sound." Italian is more conservative than Spanish, English, and French in this regard when it comes to the soft c. In the case of the soft g, this is why Mandarin speakers pronounced "Beijing" more like "Peking" before the early 20th century (it remains unpalatalized in the more conservative Chinese dialects as well as in Japanese and Korean since the word was borrowed much earlier in time).

Comment: It also appears that another round of palatalization in English called "yod-coalescence" was the reason for the final sound change to -shion after the -sion pronunciation for -tion was borrowed from French.