# Why is it thought that T resisted assibilation after another T?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

It's well known that past a certain point, Latin "t" developed an assibilated pronunciation when followed by "i" and then a vowel, as in the word *grātia.* Sources agree that there are some exceptions, most of which make intuitive sense to me; e.g. -tīV- is supposed to have resisted this development, and in -stǐV- and -xtǐV- the -t- is supposed to have remained non-assibilated.

But one thing that puzzles me is that various sources say that -ttiV- was immune to this development. From a theoretical standpoint, I can't see why a preceding -t- would be expected to prevent assibilation. The sequence -ttiV- seems to be pretty rare, so I'm also not sure about whether we actually have much evidence to support this generalization about the natural development of the pronunciation of -ttiV-. (E.g. is there compelling inscriptional or Romance-based evidence?)

[Walter Blair's *Latin Prounciation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s3NXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA119) (1873) says "For manifest natural reasons it is commonly agreed as improbable that the T could have been hissed when it was immediately preceded by another T, or by a hiss, as S or X. (See Zumpt's Lat. Gr., p. 7" (p. 119).

I confess that I haven't sought out Zumpt's grammar yet, as I thought that the members of this site might be able to tell me more quickly and in more detail whether there are actually solid reasons for supposing that -ttiV- was a special environment where the t > [ts] sound law did not apply. If anyone wants to do more digging and post an answer summarizing the results of their research, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Why puzzling? It doesn't seem too surprising that geminates should be more resistant to such changes.

Comment: @TKR: I can understand why geminates would be resistant to lenition, but the assibilation of t to [ts] in palatal contexts doesn't seem to be a lenition change. For comparison, Latin -c- was palatalized even when it followed -c-, and Japanese -t- is palatalized to [tɕ] even when geminate.

Comment: FWIW, Finnish has *ti > si* but *tti* remains unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

Since posting the question, I found a small amount of relevant information that I thought I'd put as a partial answer. I'd still appreciate answers from other members of this site!

#### Evidence from other languages showing that [t] may assibilate while [tt] does not

Assibilation of singleton [t] but not geminate [tt] seems to have occurred also in Finnic. "Towards a Typology of Stop Assibilation," by T. A. Hall and Silke Hamann (2003), says

> An argument that the length of the frication phase is perceived in relation to the overall duration of the sequence is illustrated by assibilation in Finnic. Here the /t/ was fricativized to [s] before a high front vowel, but the geminate /tt/ remained unchanged (Posti 1954: 51). This can be explained by the fact that the friction phase is perceived as longer if it follows a singleton than if it follows a geminate plosive.

([p. 125](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9520/1009ffb230382c3c6e5ca118f47cad62a3a0.pdf))

This explanation seems relatively satisfactory to me. I still would be interested in learning more details about how we know that -ttiV- did not palatalize in Latin.

#### Evidence from Romance suggesting that [tt] might have assibilated in vulgar speech

On the other hand, I found that the Italian name of the island *[Brazza](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Brazza)* is supposed to come from Latin *[Brattia](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DBrattia).* Similarly, *mattiana* seems to have developed to Asturian *[mazana](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mazana)* and Mirandese *[maçana](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%A7ana),* although Wiktionary says that *matianium* has been suggested as an alternative source.

If the pronunciations of these words developed naturally, and if they are from Latin forms with [tt] rather than coming from forms with non-geminate [t], it suggests that the rule about not assibilating *-ttiV-* may have developed artificially, rather than as a natural rule of the spoken language.

In some other sources, I've seen it suggested that *-ti-* in words from Greek might not assibilate, which seems similar and also seems like it might be an artificial rule.

Overall, I have the impression that there is not enough evidence to clearly establish whether [tti] before a vowel naturally developed differently from [ti] before a vowel in Latin. There weren't many Latin words with [tti] before a vowel.

Comment: turns out there are exceptions. For example, Hall and Hamann also mention, citing Fortescue 1984: 333, that "in West Greenlandic (see 11q) singleton and geminate /t/ are assibilated to [ts] in all contexts."